# Move Sublime Text find panel

Tags: find, sublimetext

Does anyone know if there is a way to change the location of the find/replace panel in Sublime Text 4? My issue is that when I am using Terminus to access the command line but need to find something in my document, pressing ctrl + F to search for it, closes the terminus panel which I then need to reopen. It doesn't end the session but is just an extra annoying step that I'd like to get rid of if possible.

I've tried looking at the Terminus and Sublime documentation as well as stack overflow and GitHub but I haven't managed to find anyone hoping to do the same. It's mostly people wanting to have the results open in a different tab which isn't the behavior I'm after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sublime, panels can only open at the bottom of the window, and only one panel can be visible at a time. This is one of [Jon Skinner's main design ideals](https://www.sublimetext.com/blog/articles/2007/11) when creating Sublime; maximize the amount of space dedicated to text and minimize the chrome.

As such, the only way to have both Terminus and a find panel open at the same time is to switch Terminus to execute in a tab instead of in a panel.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I didn't think of using tabs instead of a panel. I now have it so that my screen is split into two rows: one for Terminus and one for my code. P.S. thank you also for all the Sublime education and support you give! Love your videos.